# ArcGIS Solar Radiation tool says output global radiation raster empty?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, spatial-analyst, solar-radiation

I am using ArcGIS 10 with windows7 64 bit on core i7 processor
I am working with ArcMap 10 solar radiation tool to create the area solar radiation map. Every time I run the tool it stops after some time after creating raster layers that are empty. And i receive this message

> output global radiation raster empty

What should I do as it is my first experience with arctoolbox.
i have tried running tool with both

GTOPO 30 and SRTM 3 arc second data
projection coordinate for GTOPO 30 was WGS 84 
and for SRTM it was UTM

Is there something wrong with the DEM I used?
Or ArcToolBox? 
or do i need to change the environment settings?

Comment: Give us the projection information of each file from arccatalog and I think we will be able to answer your question. all vectors and all rasters.

Comment: projection information of the DEM i am using?

Comment: at first i tried with geographic coordinate WGS 84 and the DEM was GTOPO 30 and then i used SRTM 3 ars seconds and i used projected coordinate UTM.

Comment: i would really appreciate any help because i need to have some results by tomorrow morning as my project supervisor is leaving for italy.

Comment: If you have additional information that helps clarify your question in response to questions asked I would recommend using the edit button beneath your question to keep revising it.  Including things like the precise inputs that you fed to the tool would most likely be helpful here.

Comment: i have reedited the question plz see if it cab be more refined in any way so someone will answer the question and my problem will be solved